# "out of shared memory" when trying to drop or truncate a large hypertable

Tags: timescaledb

```
openmeteo=# DROP TABLE enhydris_timeseriesrecord;
ERROR:  out of shared memory
HINT:  You might need to increase max_locks_per_transaction.
```

The table has about 60 million rows, mostly with ten- or fifteen-minute data. I created it with all the defaults (`SELECT create_hypertable('enhydris_timeseriesrecord', 'timestamp')`).

Regardless whether it should have been created with other parameters, is there any way to drop it without reconfiguring PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try calling drop_chunks in smaller batches in order to pare down the number of chunks first before dropping the table?